# Netsuite Metadata Extraction through SUitescript/Webservices

Tags: netsuite

Can we extract the metadata of Netsuite using Webservices or Suitescript for Record Types ?
For example if i have a record Summary Invoices--->I need the field names and the data type of every field ?

Answer (score 3):

In SuiteScript, you can load an instance of the record you're trying to inspect, then call the `getAllFields` method on it:

```
var record = nlapiLoadRecord('customrecord_summaryinvoice', 'anyInternalIdHere');
var fieldNames = record.getAllFields();

// Do whatever you need to with fieldNames...
```

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Web Services enough to recommend an approach there.

Comment: I would have a follow up question
i)  how will i get the list of all custom records plus 
ii) if a record doesn't exist for the record type we cant extract out the fields we first need to create a record 
Do we have a work around for the above 2 questions ?

Comment: NetSuite's metadata discovery is unfortunately lacking. I don't know of a good way to programmatically get the list of all custom records. One option for your second question is to manually create a single record of that type, then just mark it inactive. You can still load an inactive record with `nlapiLoadRecord`, but it will not show up in normal search results or other lists.

Comment: Thanks egrubaugh360
Will writing a crawler to extract data and get a list of metadata/custom records a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In SuiteTalk there is an API call you can make which will return the meta data (scriptId, internalId) for all Custom Records.

I'm using C#:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetCustomization()
{

    Dictionary<string, string> customRecords = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // gets metadata for all custom records.
    CustomizationType ct = new CustomizationType() { 
        getCustomizationType = GetCustomizationType.customRecordType, 
        getCustomizationTypeSpecified = true 
    };

    GetCustomizationIdResult  cr = _myNetSuiteWebReference.getCustomizationId(ct, false);

    foreach (CustomizationRef re in cr.customizationRefList)
    {
        customRecords.Add(re.scriptId, re.internalId);
    }

    return customRecords;
}
```

If you've already loaded a record using web services, you can use Reflection to get the properties of that object.

I'm going to use a Sales Order record just for an example:

```
RecordRef rr = new RecordRef();
rr.internalId = "123456789";
rr.typeSpecified = true;
rr.type = RecordType.salesOrder;

ReadResponse readr = Get(rr);
// cast so a sales order object.
SalesOrder so = (SalesOrder)readr.record;

so.getType().getProperties(); // returns an array of PropertyInfo.
foreach(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in so.getType().getProperties())
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(pi.Name);
}
```